# Why im getting this error Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max?

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, emulation

When im trying to run my application on iOS emulator im getting this error
Does anyone know why im getting this ?

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/name/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.7.3/ios/Classes/FLTImagePickerPlugin.m:149:20: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", nil)
                       ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/name/project/project/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/image_picker/image_picker-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIAlertView : UIView
               ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/name/projectname/projectname/ios/Pods/Regift/Regift/AVAssetImageGeneratorTimePoints.swift:12:5: warning: 'public' modifier is redundant for instance method declared in a public extension
        public func generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimePoints(timePoints: [TimePoint], completionHandler: @escaping AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler) {
        ^~~~~~~
    /Users/name/project/project/ios/Pods/Regift/Regift/Regift.swift:251:45: error: missing argument label 'preferredTimescale:' in call
                let time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, Constants.TimeInterval)
                                                ^
                                                          preferredTimescale:
    /Users/name/project/project/ios/Pods/Regift/Regift/Regift.swift:303:46: error: missing argument label 'preferredTimescale:' in call
            let tolerance = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Constants.Tolerance, Constants.TimeInterval)
                                                 ^
                                                                       preferredTimescale:
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

The app was running perfectly on the last week but I dont know why it dont built now ?

After taking some changes from user @Huthaifa Muayyad This is the error now

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                           25,2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/name/projectname/projetcname/ios/Pods/Regift/Regift/AVAssetImageGeneratorTimePoints.swift:12:5: warning: 'public' modifier is redundant for instance method declared in a public extension
        public func generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimePoints(timePoints: [TimePoint], completionHandler: @escaping AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler) {
        ^~~~~~~
    /Users/name/projectname/projectname/ios/Pods/Regift/Regift/Regift.swift:251:45: error: missing argument label 'preferredTimescale:' in call
                let time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, Constants.TimeInterval)
                                                ^
                                                          preferredTimescale:
    /Users/name/projectname/projectname/ios/Pods/Regift/Regift/Regift.swift:303:46: error: missing argument label 'preferredTimescale:' in call
            let tolerance = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Constants.Tolerance, Constants.TimeInterval)
                                                 ^
                                                                       preferredTimescale:
    gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp-cxhudvivvbfckkebvhcbvchzlxji
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uncommenting the first line ios/Podfile and update it to `10.0`,

Your error also says `UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead` Try updating imagepicker if you are using it.

Comment: I do what you want but now getting another error I will update my post please check out

Comment: Ok please check

Comment: it's telling you `error: missing argument label 'preferredTimescale:' in call`

Comment: What does that mean ?

Comment: check out this thread https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37447

Comment: Yes!! I dont know why but it works now thank you have a nice day !

Comment: Have a beautiful day yourself, happy coding! :)